# Azure DevOps Pipeline artifact download stalls and eventually fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Some of my pipelines are unable to fully download a pipeline artifact during the second stage. It's a very simple pipeline, and I use the exact same structure with other repos that are successful. I'm using a self-hosted agent defined in the 'default' pool.

Pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: doDeploy
  displayName: Deploy
  type: boolean
  default: true

variables:
  version: '1.0.0'

name: $(version).$(rev:r)
trigger: [ main ]

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool: default
    workspace:
      clean: outputs
    steps:
    - script: |
        cd bundle
        7z a -tzip -r $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bundle.jsdos .
        cd ../
        if [ -e ./screenshot.png ]
        then
          cp ./screenshot.png $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        fi
      displayName: 'Creating game bundle'

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: $(Build.DefinitionName)

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ parameters.doDeploy }}, eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  pool: default
  variables:
    deployLocation: /var/deploy/catalog/$(Build.Repository.Name)
  jobs:
    - deployment: deploy
      environment: production
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: none
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                artifact: $(Build.DefinitionName)
                path: $(deployLocation)
```

This repo only has a few files that are a part of the zip process. To debug I removed the files one-by-one and found that when I removed a specific file the deploy was successful. This seems (to me) to point to something related to the deduplication of that file not working correctly, but I don't know how I would fix it. I've deleted and re-created the pipeline to see if that would clear the deduplication status for artifacts, but it still fails.

Here are some example errors reported from the verbose logging. I can post the entire log somewhere if it would help, but it's too big for the body of this question

```
2023-03-11T21:12:41.1291729Z Verbose, Details:
2023-03-11T21:12:41.1291928Z No LastRequestResponse on exception HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (0t3vsblobprodcus362.blob.core.windows.net:443)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3171965Z Verbose, [https://37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net/dbb87b827bc5964c46b38b4867357ef8c2/A2F82CD2F4354888B3681D296734F5A8E1621BDF1B9956762144F32B776E539F01?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2023-03-12T21:38:10Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a25371dd-4d4a4f62-95e9c414-312423e7-session-e4da57fb-5a7b4e1c-90bf741d-94c4186f] Try 4/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:07.9614178. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net:443)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3173308Z  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3173577Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3173956Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3174293Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3174813Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3175207Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3175469Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3175838Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3176145Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3176477Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3176737Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3177031Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3177601Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3178078Z    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3178505Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3178966Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3179362Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.RequestHandler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3179709Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3179939Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3180177Z Verbose, Details:
2023-03-11T21:12:41.3180412Z No LastRequestResponse on exception HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net:443)
2023-03-11T21:12:45.7662643Z Information, Downloaded 1.7 MB out of 2.1 MB (81%).
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2835634Z Verbose, [https://37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net/dbb87b827bc5964c46b38b4867357ef8c2/A2F82CD2F4354888B3681D296734F5A8E1621BDF1B9956762144F32B776E539F01?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2023-03-12T21:38:10Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-a25371dd-4d4a4f62-95e9c414-312423e7-session-e4da57fb-5a7b4e1c-90bf741d-94c4186f] Try 5/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:14.4706107. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net:443)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2837377Z  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2837639Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2837923Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2838385Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2838724Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2839096Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2839339Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2839658Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2839941Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2840207Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2840462Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2840754Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2841094Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2841573Z    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2841961Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2842384Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2842725Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.RequestHandler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2843052Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2843288Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2843478Z Verbose, Details:
2023-03-11T21:12:49.2843702Z No LastRequestResponse on exception HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net:443)
```

It remains stuck at 2.0 MB until it eventually fails.

Comment: Resource temporarily unavailable sometime point to RAM issue, can you check the RAM in the machine during the pipeline?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I believe that is the http status being returned from the *.blob.core.microsoft.net endpoint, not coming from the agent machine. So I do not have access to the baking server to look at ram usage.